# How this $ \exp(i 10 \pi)^{\frac56}=\exp(\frac{i \pi}{3})$ true in the below paper ? And how is de Moivre's formula applied for non integer exponent?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I discussed with my friend the following problem which is related to [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145241?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which is written by Curtis D. Bennett, A. M. W. Glass and Gábor J. Székely under this title **Fermat's Last Theorem for Rational Exponents** in Monthly American journal  , Really in the introduction Authors wrote for the identity :$1^{5/6}+1^{5/6}=1^{5/6}$ , They wrote :$ \exp(i 10 \pi)^{\frac56}=\exp(\frac{i  \pi}{3})$ , How this true and how $10$ comes ? and how is [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) applied here for rational number for non integer exponent?? I did many attempt to let de Moivre's formula applied for integers but I failed ?

[image]

Comment: in $\mathbb C$, there are $6$ sixth roots of $1$

Comment: Thanks but how 10 comes in the exponent  ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The author specifically picked 10 because it works. Recall that $$\exp(2ni\pi)=1$$ for all integer values of $n$. Thus, if we picked $n=5$, we would get the $10$. Euler's formula should explain your questions.

Comment: it's *de Moivre*

Answer (score 2):

$\exp(i 10 \pi)^{5/6} = \exp(i \pi 50/6) = \exp(i \pi 8) . \exp (i \pi /3) = \exp (i \pi /3)$

Indeed $1^{5/6}$ shall refer a to real root of 1. But I think this is why the authors write "new" solution (in quotation mark).

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb C$, if we say $\zeta=1^{1/6}$ means $\zeta^6=1$, there are $6$ possibilities for $\zeta$:

$\exp(2\pi i/6), \exp(4\pi i/6), \exp(6\pi i/6)=-1, \exp(8\pi i/6), \exp(10\pi i/6),$ and $ \exp(12\pi i/6)=1$,

and thus $6$ possibilities for $\zeta^5$:

$\exp(10\pi i/6)=\color{green}{\exp(5\pi i/3)}, \exp(20\pi i/6), \exp(30\pi i/6)=-1, \exp(40\pi i/6), $

$\exp(50\pi i/6)=\color{brown}{\exp(\pi i/3)}$, and $  \exp(60\pi i/6)=\color{blue}1$.

Now $\color{green}{\exp(5\pi i/3)}+\color{brown}{\exp(\pi i/3)}=\color{blue}1,$

so we can have $\color{green}{1^{5/6}}+\color{brown}{1^{5/6}}=\color{blue}{1^{5/6}}$ by making different choices for $1^{5/6}$.

Comment: Nice answer , Thnaks

Comment: Choices of k are k,0,1,2 in this case

Answer (score 0):

The De Moivre formula only works with integers, otherwise you would have
$$ \forall\theta\in\mathbb{R},e^{i\theta}=(e^{2i\pi})^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}=1^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}=1 $$
Moreover, the definition of $1^{5/6}$ is (for me) $1^{5/6}:=e^{\frac{5}{6}\ln 1}$ so that $1^{5/6}=1$ and thus $1^{5/6}+1^{5/6}=2\neq 1^{5/6}$.

Answer (score 0):

we know that $\exp(2πi)=\exp(10πi)$.
so if Moivre formula works with rational number
we get: $ \exp(2πi)^{5/6}=\exp(5πi/3)=\exp(-iπ/3)$
   and: $\exp(10πi)^{5/6}=\exp(50πi/6)=\exp(iπ/3)$
contradiction.

Comment: look to the answer above by @user114285

Comment: This claim $\exp(10πi)^{5/6}=\exp(50πi/3)=\exp(iπ/3)$ is true look the answer above by @user11485