# Proof of $ \exp(2πi)^{5/6}=\exp(5πi/3)=\exp(-iπ/3)$

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation

I have tried many times to convince my self that the following claim  $ \exp(2πi)^{5/6}=\exp(5πi/3)=\exp(-iπ/3)$ being true but I can't .

Assume $ \exp(2πi)=\exp(10πi)$   then we have 
$ \exp(2πi)^5/6=\exp(5πi/3)=\exp(−iπ/3)$

and $ \exp(10πi)^{5/6}=\exp(50πi/6)=\exp(iπ/3)$ which it is a contradiction .

Now my question here : Does there exist a such proof for which De Moivre formula applied for rational number ?

Comment: If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The power laws don't hold in general for complex numbers. However, if $a=b$ then $a^c=b^c$ is always true

Comment: It's *de Moivre*

Answer (score 6):

Just because $e^{2\pi i} =e^{10\pi i} $ does not mean that $e^{2a\pi i} =e^{10a\pi i} $ for all $a$. The rule
$$(a^b)^c=a^{bc} $$
does not hold in general for complex numbers.

Comment: @zair Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Complex powers are multivalued functions and since sadly modern mathematics kind of frowns upon those, there is a lot of confusion around. Personally I think of them as (generally infinite) sets until we are in an analytic context where branches that give unique values can be fixed.

So here $A=${$\exp(2πi)^{5/6}$} ={$\exp (\frac{5}{6}\log \exp 2\pi i)$}={$\exp (\frac{5}{6}(2\pi i k)), k \in \mathbb Z$}. In particular $A$ contains $1, e^{\frac{5\pi i}{3}}, e^{\frac{10\pi i}{3}}= e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}},e^{\frac{15\pi i}{3}}=-1, e^{\frac{20\pi i}{3}}=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}},e^{\frac{25\pi i}{3}}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$ as it has $6$ elements by periodicity

Similarly  $B=${$\exp(10πi)^{5/6}$} ={$\exp (\frac{5}{6}\log \exp 10\pi i)$}={$\exp (\frac{5}{6}(10\pi i k)), k \in \mathbb Z$} and one can convince themselves that $B$ has also $6$ elements which are unsurpsingly the same as those in $A$

So as from the equality of sets {$-1,1$}={$-1,1$} one cannot conclude that $1=-1$, similarly from the equality sets $A=B$ one cannot conclude that distinct elements (eg $e^{\frac{5\pi i}{3}}$ in $A$ and $e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$ in $B$ )in one set are equal so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you are raising a sixth root of $1$ to the fifth power.  This gives you a sixth root of $1$ again.  Since there are $6$ complex sixth roots of $1$, the symbol $\exp(2\pi i)^{5/6}$ is perhaps best understood as multi-valued, indicating any of the sixth roots of $1$, or perhaps it should be understood as indicating the set of all six of them, $\{e^{k\pi i/3}|k=0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.  If we interpret $\exp(10\pi i)^{5/6}$, in the same manner, then the second interpretation gives no problem.  In the first interpretation, $\exp(2\pi i)^{5/6}=\exp(10\pi i)^{5/6}$ simply means that there is some complex number which is a possible value of both expressions.

In any case, as others have said, rules of exponents are different for complex numbers.

Comment: thank you. So is this exp(i10π)^5/6=exp(iπ50/6)=exp(iπ8).exp(iπ/3)=exp(iπ/3) true?

Comment: @zairmohamed Please use MathJax so I can read what you are writing.

Comment: @zairmohamed do u meant :$\exp(i 10 \pi)^{5/6} = \exp(i \pi 50/6) = \exp(i \pi 8) . \exp (i \pi /3) = \exp (i \pi /3)$ ? if so , yes it is true

Comment: @zeraouliarafik It's true in the sense that $e^{i\pi/3}$ is a possible value of $\left( e^{10\pi i}\right)^{5/6}$.  This should not be taken to be a single-valued symbol.  With real numbers we have a convention to take the positive value when there are two choices, but this doesn't work for complex numbers.

Comment: @saulspatz, As zair Mohamed   said to me that the formula which montioned in the introduction of  [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145241?read-now=1&seq=1) is  which states that $1^{5/6}+1^{5/6}=1^{5/6}$  not true because it uses $\exp(i 10 \pi)^{5/6} = \exp(i \pi 50/6) = \exp(i \pi 8) . \exp (i \pi /3) = \exp (i \pi /3)$

Comment: @saulspatz , The truth is that I read this result in a research paper:

$$ 1^{5/6} + 1^{5/6} =1^{5/6} $$ 

the researcher proved the result with what I mentioned, and I feel confused about what he has done.

Comment: @zairmohamed It would have been good to mention this in the question.  Where did you see this paper?

Comment: The paper is Bennett, Curtis D., A. M. W. Glass, and Gábor J. Székely. "Fermat's Last Theorem for Rational Exponents." The American Mathematical Monthly 111, no. 4 (2004): 322-29.

Comment: @zairmohamed They explain in the first paragraph how the equation $1^{5/6} + 1^{5/6} =1^{5/6}$ is to be interpreted.  Obviously, they don't intend that the symbol $1^{5/6}$ be given the same meaning throughout.  But if you take to mean, as I suggested, that there are two sixth roots of $1$ whose sum is another sixth root of $1$, then it's true, and unremarkable.

Comment: @saulspatz , I'm very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think The OP meant the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633315/156150) of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3633295/156150) He may want to ask why this :$$\exp(i 10 \pi)^{5/6} = \exp(i \pi 50/6) = \exp(i \pi 8) . \exp (i \pi /3) = \exp (i \pi /3)$$ is true , But this is true for unit complex roots which it has six root  as shown in all answers there , In particular [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633324/156150), that is the reason why He asked for existence of  such de formula which is not valide for Rational number and in the same time the part of this question is the same of his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633375/156150)